# Graphing a function containing ln

Tags: plotting

I have been trying to graph this function but it won’t work! I cannot figure out what I’m doing wrong. It contains a natural log, but is not purely a log function. Can anyone help?

```
F[x_]:=10Ln[(10+Sqrt[100-x^2])/x]-Sqrt[(100-x^2)]
Plot[F[x],{x,0,10}]
```

Comment: Use `Log` vice `Ln`

Comment: In Mathematica you use the function `Log[x]` for the natural logarithm $ln(x)$ and `Log10[x]` for $log_{10}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed it. Such a simple thing...